# Binding @Provides method as eager singleton

Tags: java, guice

I want to make a binding using a method annotated with `@Provides` into an eager singleton. I've found [bug 216](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=216), which suggests this isn't possible, but doesn't mention the `@Provides` annotation explicitly.

I currently have a class that requests the `eager` singletons in time by itself being a singleton, but it's not a very nice solution.

```
public class LogicModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override public void configure() {
        bind(SomeDep.class);
        bind(MyWorkaround.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

    // cannot add eager requirement here
    @Provides @Singleton Logic createLogic(SomeDep dep) {
        return LogicCreator.create(dep);
    }

    private static class MyWorkaround {
        @Inject Logic logic;
    }
}
```

Can I change something near the comment that would make the workaround class obsolete?

Comment: In the bug report you linked, "provider methods" means "methods annotated with @Provides".  So you're right, it's not directly possible.  But comment #11 on that bug report shows a better workaround than yours IMO (use a Provider<> instead).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not to use

```
bind(Logic.class).toInstance(LogicCreator.create(dep)); 
//ohh we missing dep
```

then we can do this

```
class LogicProvider implements Provider<Logic> {

    private final SomeDep dep;

    @Inject
    public LogicProvider(SomeDep dep) {
      this.dep = dep;
    }

    @Override
    public Logic get() {
      return LogicCreator.create(dep);
    }

}
```

and then

```
bind(Logic.class).toProvider(LogicProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

You can even pass `SomeDep dep` to your provider as `Provider<SomeDep>` and then call `providerDep.get()` in `LogicCreator.create()` that would be a bit more robust.